# How to get column value in excel, shifting position?

Tags: excel

Considerer this table

```
A1       B1      C1         M1      N1       .........

Jan 11, Feb 11, Mar 11....Dec 11, Jan 12, Feb 12, Mar 12... Dec 12
```

I need alternating Month like this:

```
Jan 11, Jan 12, Diff Jan, Feb 11, Feb 12, Diff Feb ..... Dec 11, Dec 12, Diff 12
```

Which formulas can i use to rebuild the table ?

For example i can go at the end of the first table and to get jan 12 i've to insert a formula like

```
column A+12
```

Is it possible in Excel ?

EDIT: what i need is to create a formula, to move the month of the second year near the month of the first year.

Comment: your question doesn't make much sense tbh, could you clear it up please?

Comment: I think you might require a macro for that.

Comment: Your question isn't very clear, but I think what you may be after is the `OFFSET` formula. Example: `=OFFSET(A1,,12)` would give the cell 12 to the right of A1.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience the format you start with has been much more convenient that what I understand you to want but the choice is yours so I would suggest:

1. Add a row at the top with `1` in A1, drag A1 across to L1 with
   <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> depressed, and copy those 12 cells to M1 and to Y1.
2. In Y3 (or adjust to suit) put `=X3-W3`, copy across to AJ3 and copy
   Y3:AJ3 down to suit.
3. Select A:AJ, sort on Row1 Smallest to Largest and delete that row.
4. Add labels to suit.